# What is -1 and 0 doing in date add function?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
dateadd(mm, DATEPART(MONTH, DATE) - 1, 0) + DATEPART(DAY, DATE) - 1
```

OUTPUT date is in the year for example 1990-12-02 00:00:00:000

Full query is below:

```
SELECT dateadd(yy, (
            DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) + (
                CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, GP_DATE) > 10
                        THEN 0
                    ELSE 1
                    END
                ) - 1900
            ), 0) + dateadd(mm, DATEPART(MONTH, GP_DATE) - 1, 0) + DATEPART(DAY, GP_DATE) - 1 GP_DATE
from table
```

I am trying to convert this query into snowflake syntax and snowflake syntax dateadd function does not allow 1, 0.

Comment: The whole thing is very odd. If `GP_DATE` is in October or earlier, it'll give you that date in next year (ignoring Feb 29th for time being). If it's in November or December, it'll give you the day before that date in the current year. No idea if that's what the *intention* of the query was. Seems an odd spec.

Comment: dateadd function only takes YY/mm/dd, value, date. i don't understand how this query is accepting -1 and 0?  I ran dateadd(mm, DATEPART(MONTH, GP_DATE) - 1, 0) + DATEPART(DAY, GP_DATE) - 1 and all dates are coming in year 1990. That's what I am not clear on. I am trying to convert  above query into snowflake and I am getting different  dates.

Comment: This doesn't look like MySQL syntax. Is it SQL Server? Why the `mysqli` tag?

Comment: What is the *input* date?  Please describe what the code is supposed to be doing.  You have two queries, so it is unclear what your real question is.  However, it is probably quite answerable . . . if it were clear.  Your question should not be about arcane syntax in SQL Server.  It should be about how to do something in Snowflake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, there are some rather ugly implicit conversions available between datetimes and integers.

`0`, when converted to a date, becomes `1900-01-01`.

You're also allowed to do maths on dates. Adding or subtracting `1` adds or subtracts 1 day from the date. Putting these facts together, we have:

```
dateadd(yy, (
        DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) + (
            CASE 
                WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, GP_DATE) > 10
                    THEN 0
                ELSE 1
                END
            ) - 1900
        ), 0)
```

Which is taking the current year, and subtracting 1900 from it (or 1899 if the month is less than 11, for whatever reason). We then take that number and add it back to the date `0` (which as stated above is `1900-01-01`). The result is that we get the first of January of next year or this year, depending on the month of `GP_DATE`. Call this `D1`.

Moving on:

```
dateadd(mm, DATEPART(MONTH, GP_DATE) - 1, 0)
```

is taking the month of `GP_DATE`, subtracting `1` from it and adding that number of months to the date `0` (`1900-01-01`). The result is a the 1st of whichever month `GP_DATE` is in, but in `1900`. Let's call this `D2`.

When we add `D1` and `D2` together, we approximately get a date of the 1st of whichever month `GP_DATE` is in, in either this year or next year. Note, however, that this goes wrong if the `D1` year is a leap year, we get it wrong by a day for months after `February`.

Finally, we take `DATEPART(DAY, GP_DATE) - 1`, where we take the day of the month from `GP_DATE`, subtract `1`, and add that on to our result so far. This should set the final date to be on the same day of the month as `GP_DATE`, except for the error mentioned above.

---

So, it appears that the code is trying to take `GP_DATE` and get the same date in either this year or next year, depending on how late in the year `GP_DATE` is. However, it also appears it was never tested with consideration for leap years.

A far more likely correct version of this query would be this instead:

```
SELECT
DATEADD(year,
   DATEDIFF(year,GP_DATE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) +
   CASE WHEN DATEPART(month,GP_DATE)>10 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
,GP_DATE)
```

Comment: Thank you. You explained very well however there was an ambiguity in my query. Truly appreciated. Following you now :)